# Ending bounty with "off topic" answer

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Refering to this question on stackoverflow: [Android exploit dalvik classes: Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146258/)
I have set a bounty on 150 reputation and the bounty is ending tomorrow. Last time I set a bounty and the bounty ended, there was 1 answer; not on the topic. When the bounty ended this automaticely awarded half of the bounty to the anwser. Will this happen to this question ?

Comment: In short: only if the answer will have score of 2 or more.

Comment: Ok, thx @ShaWizDowArd